# Not able to connect to SOLR through CloudSolrClient?

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrj, solrcloud

I am facing some issue while connecting to Solr through `CloudSolrClient`.
 I used the following piece of code.

```
CloudSolrClient server = new CloudSolrClient("ip:8983");
server.setDefaultCollection("hadoop_logs_shard3_replica1");
```

I am getting following error

```
    java.io.IOException: Packet len1213486160 is out of range!
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket.readLength(ClientCnxnSocket.java:112)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:79)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public CloudSolrClient(String zkHost)
```

> Create a new client object that connects to `Zookeeper` and is always aware of the SolrCloud state. Updates will be sent to shard leaders by default.

You are specifying solr instance `host:port` instead of zookeeper `host:port`. Fix that, It should work afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

1213486160 is ASCII "HTTP" interpreted as a 32-bit big-endian integer. As YoungHobbit suggests, you are not speaking to the correct service.